# How to upgrade PrestaShop to an unreleased official version like (1.7.8 or 1.7.7)?

Tags: php, prestashop, e-commerce

The PHP of the server is 7.4.4. I've upgraded a Prestashop to the official latest version (1.7.5) but, this version not compatible with the PHP version(7.4.4).

On the other hand, the hosting provider, can not downgrade the PHP version until (7.3).

So, I want to upgrade the old Prestashop to an unreleased version like v1.7.7 or 1.7.8 which compatible with PHP 7.3 or 7.4.4.

So, there is a way for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop 1.7.7 or 1.7.8 don't exist yet, they have not been released.